# Bootstrap navbar with tab links not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navbar

Here is the question. 
   The contents of Home link are shown by default. but when i click the link like About us or Contact us do not show. Here is the bootstrap code i used. Please tell me how to show up the links in navbar.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>Savitasoft</title>
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
      </head>
    <body>

        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="pull-left" href="#"> 
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/images/test.png"></img>
              </a>
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#About_us">About us</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#Contact_us">Contact us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      <div class="tab-content" >
        <div id="Home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
           <p>These are the contents of Home </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Services" class="tab-pane fade">
           <p>These are the contents of Services </p>
        </div>
        <div id="About_us" class="tab-pane fade">
           <p>These are the contents of About us </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Contact_us" class="tab-pane fade">
           <p>These are the contents of Contact us </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use Jquery to do this

Answer (score 2):

Use  `data-toggle=tab` in the links.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"> <a href="#Home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#Services" data-toggle="tab">Services</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#About_us" data-toggle="tab">About us</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#Contact_us" data-toggle="tab">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/KMm35WHGZR

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be helped

```
<script>
   //Functon to show divs from the nav menu
    function show_div(toShow)
    {
       var show = document.getElementById(toShow);
       show.style.display = "";
    }
</script>
```

Then call this method when click the navbar link using

```
 <a href="#" onclick="show_div('home');"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added data-toggle="tab" in all the `<a>` tags and it worked without jquery.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"> <a href="#Home" data-toggle="tab" >Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#Services" data-toggle="tab" >Services</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#About_us" data-toggle="tab" >About us</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#Contact_us" data-toggle="tab">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
```